# How can I remove the space before a custom theorem-like environment header?

Tags: pdftex, amsthm, thmtools

I have created a custom theorem-like environment using the package `thmtools` commands `\declaretheoremstyle` and `\declaretheorem`. The header of the environment is supposed to be given as an option at the point of use of the environment. The MWE given below defines the custom theorem-like environment `custdef` as an example of a custom theorem-like environment. The MWE defines the custom theorem with the header **Pellentesque Habitant** as an instance of the environment `custdef`. The MWE compiles. However, an *unwanted space* appears before the header in the typeset text.

Could someone advise me on how I could get rid of the *unwanted space*. The desired solution should work for any reasonable value of the option `postheadspace`. I would appreciate any help towards solving the problem.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{nameref}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[%
    spaceabove    = \topsep,%
    spacebelow    = \topsep,%
    notefont      = \bfseries,%
    bodyfont      = \normalfont\itshape,%
    headpunct     = .,%
    notebraces    = {}{},%
    postheadspace = 0.5em,%
    headindent    = \z@,%
    headformat    = \NOTE
]{CDStyle}

\declaretheorem[
    heading       = {},
    numbered      = no,
    refname       = \NOTE,
    preheadhook   = \vskip\z@,%
    postfoothook  = \vskip\z@,%
    style         = CDStyle
]{custdef}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi
dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur
auctor semper nulla.

\begin{custdef}[Pellentesque Habitant]
Pellentesque Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
fames ac turpis egestas viverra metus rhoncus sem dictum gravida.
\end{custdef}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer
id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The space is due to `\thmt@space`, that you can nullify with a suitable setting of `preheadhook`.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{nameref}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove    = \topsep,
    spacebelow    = \topsep,
    notefont      = \bfseries,
    bodyfont      = \normalfont\itshape,
    headpunct     = .,
    notebraces    = {}{},
    postheadspace = 0.5em,
    headindent    = 0pt,
    headformat    = \NOTE,
]{CDStyle}

\makeatletter
\declaretheorem[
    preheadhook   = \renewcommand{\thmt@space}{},
    numbered      = no,
    refname       = \NOTE,
    style         = CDStyle
]{custdef}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\nameref{foo}

Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi
dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur
auctor semper nulla.

\begin{custdef}[Pellentesque Habitant]\label{foo}
Pellentesque Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
fames ac turpis egestas viverra metus rhoncus sem dictum gravida.
\end{custdef}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer
id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg. Your solution to the problem works perfectly for me. I had feared that the redefinition of the command `\thmt@space` would have a global effect. I have confirmed that the effect of the redefinition is, fortunately,  localized  to the environment `custdef`.

Comment: @user24098 That's the purpose of `preheadhook`. It may be a problem if you nest other statements, I didn't test.

Comment: Thanks once more @egreg. May I seek some clarification. You have specified `\unskip\NOTE` as the value of the  option `headformat` in your declaration of `CDStyle`. Is the `\unskip` command necessary? I have noticed that its removal does not affect the typeset output. Does it have to be included to take care of a situation that is not covered by the MWE?

Comment: @user24098 Sorry, I forgot to remove it

Answer (score 1):

You can hack and set the head indent to the – interwordspace. I took the liberty to slightly simplify you code, as `title` `heading` and  `name` are synonyms:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{nameref}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[%
spaceabove = \topsep,%
spacebelow = \topsep,%
notefont = \bfseries,%
bodyfont = \normalfont\itshape,%
headpunct = .,%
notebraces = {}{},%
postheadspace = 0.5em,%
headindent =-\fontdimen2\font, %
headformat =\NOTE
]{CDStyle}

\declaretheorem[
numbered =no,
name = {},
refname =\NOTE,
preheadhook = \vskip\z@,%
postfoothook = \vskip\z@,%
style = CDStyle
]{custdef}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi
dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur
auctor semper nulla.

\begin{custdef}[Pellentesque Habitant]
  Pellentesque Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
  fames ac turpis egestas viverra metus rhoncus sem dictum gravida.
\end{custdef}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer
id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added (06/06)*

This is simpler to obtain, without a hack, with package `ntheorem`: it has an `empty` theorem style, which prints only the optional argument. Unfortunately, it adds no separator after the optional argument. Fortunately, it has a `\renewtheoremstyle` command which allowed me to add a `\labelseparator`.  So here is what you have to ad to your preamble to make ntheorem do what you want:

```
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{empty}%
{\item[]}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont \hskip\labelsep\relax ##3\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{empty}
\theoremprework{\labelsep=0.5em}
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{.\hspace{0.5em}}
\newtheorem{custdef}{}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution and  the modification that you made to my code. The appearance of synonymous option was an oversight on my part. Your code works for the given value of the option `postheadspace`. However, changing the value of the option to `0.7em` or `0.9em`, for example, changes the indentation of the header. What could be done to make the solution insensitive to changes in the value of `postheadspace`?

Comment: I'm afraid this is due to the way `thmtools` (or `amsthm`) manages the underlying list settings. All I could find with my solution was th add a factor > 1, say for `postheadspace=0.9em`, use `headindent =-1.4\fontdimen2\font`, but that's a hack. Fortunately, I suppose one doesn't change  the value  of `headindent` very often. This being say, this is quite simpler, and requires no hack, if you load `ntheorem` in the place of `amsthm`. I'll post a code in a moment.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard for the solution based on the use of package `ntheorem`. I have tried it out. It works well and requires simpler code.

Comment: It has another advantage w.r.t. amsthm: the automatic placement of the end-of-theorem/proof symbol, even when the environment ends up in a multiline displayed equation. It also can cooperate  with `thmtools`, with some restrictions.